# java jvm 11 don't start

Tags: java, windows, jvm, java-11

os: windows 10
java : 11.0.1

i setting Environmental variable

```
set JAVA_HOME=<null>

set CLASSPATH=<null>

set PATH='d:\java\jdk-11.0.1\bin
```

cmd runing

java -version

cmd runing

```
java -version
```

return this error:

> ```
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null charset name
>     at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(java.base/Charset.java:455)
>     at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(java.base/Charset.java:608)
>     at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(java.base/StringCoding.java:316)
>     at java.lang.String.(java.base/String.java:592)
>     at java.lang.String.(java.base/String.java:614)
>     at java.lang.System.initProperties(java.base/Native Method)
>     at java.lang.System.initPhase1(java.base/System.java:1942)
> ```

i try

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

same error

my jdk8 is ok

my jdk 11 is ok at company computer

what?

Comment: Setting the file.encoding should ensure this value is not null. I can only assume you have an environment variable related to character encoding it doesn't like.

Comment: yes , i have setting file.encoding to utf-8 or utf8 or "utf-8" , same error.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey the problem is that the system properties are not initialized yet. As visible in the stack trace, the system is right in the process of initializing them. Unfortunately, `initProperties` is a native method, so it’s not so easy to find out, under which circumstances it may create such a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: @Holger good point. As you say, the property is not set because it is trying to set it.

Comment: @Holger having a quick look at the native code, and I can't say how it ever worked, yet it does. I can't debug it.

Comment: This seems like a JDK bug. It does not handle the locale of your system properly. What locale is configured in Windows settings and what codepage is used?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Yes I can't debug it, This is really bad

Comment: @apangin, yes, And I still can't reproduce it on other computers.

Comment: @yanite what is default locale set on your machine? as you have mentioned "my jdk 11 is ok at company computer" does this mean it worked fine before?

Comment: @Fairoz ,my default locale is zh-CN , yes , company computer jdk 11 , is ok , my home computer is bad.

Comment: my try cygwin 32 and lxss bash , same error  Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null charset name

Comment: i using process monitor analysis it , There may be errors in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackzh-cn_17134.18.26.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Windows\System32\zh-CN\tzres.dll.mui

Comment: Oh my god, not saved.

Comment: @yan So you mean to say issue is with locale file not java?

Comment: @Fairzo yes, it can is environment issuse, my os windows 10 1083.17134.346

Answer (score 0):

This problem can reproduce in simplified chinese Windows with gb18030 support package installed.
I trace it with process monitor, saw the process end with some buffer overflow error, while loading font file named simsun gb18030(something like this, I don't remember clearly.)
this problem exist at any version of hotspot jvm after JDK 11.
but for j9 vm, there's no problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you use ideaC-2020.3.win, try jbr.

Comment: Eg.set JAVA_HOME = D:\Program Files\ideaIC-2020.3.win\jbr